# Error in my nested loop in iteration?

Tags: python

consider

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

i = 0

j = 1

for i in range(len(a)):

       for j in range(len(a)):

          d = (a[i]-a[j])
          j = j + 1
          print i, j, d
       i = i + 1
```

Output

```
0 1 0

0 2 -1 

0 3 -2

0 4 -3

1 1 1

1 2 0

1 3 -1

1 4 -2

2 1 2

2 2 1

2 3 0

2 4 -1

3 1 3

3 2 2

3 3 1

3 4 0
```

I am trying to iterate through my array so that I can only get numbers that are non-zero for d and that I do not go over the same i and j (ex: if i = 0,j=1 or i=1, j=0). Its just like doing a combination problem for which I am looking the number of pairs in my array and the d that goes for it.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Also, `i=0` and `j=0` doesn't do anything. Iterating through the `for i in range(len(a))` starts out `i` as 0. And iterating `for j in range(len(a))` starts `j` as 0. To iterate from `j=1` to `len(a)`, do: `for j in range(1, len(a))`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `permutations` from `itertools`:

```
import itertools
a = [1,2,3,4]
for permutation in itertools.permutation(a, 2):
    print permutation
```

outputs

```
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 1)
(2, 3)
...
...
```

If you also want the distances you can do

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
for permutation in itertools.permutation(a, 2):
    print permutation, permutation[1] - permutation[0]

(1, 2) 1
(1, 3) 2
(1, 4) 3
(2, 1) -1
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually using combinations from itertools was precisely what I was looking for. This led me to it though.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to iterate through my array so that I can only get numbers
>   that are non-zero for d

Unless this is a home work I would advise you to use [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) with a reverse sorted list or [itertools.permutations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) for your problem

```
>>> list((a,b) for a,b in itertools.permutations(a, 2) if a > b)
[(2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(sorted(a, reverse = True), 2))
[(4, 3), (4, 2), (4, 1), (3, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

i = 0

j = 1

for i in range(len(a)):

    for j in range(len(a)):

        d = (a[i]-a[j])
        j = j + 1
        if i != j and d != 0:
            print i, j, d
    i = i + 1
```

Output:

```
>>> 
0 2 -1
0 3 -2
0 4 -3
1 3 -1
1 4 -2
2 1 2
2 4 -1
3 1 3
3 2 2
```